# Changed a mysql page to mysqli and now the google maps initMap function is throwing an error?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

I changed this page to mysqli and switched the database. All I changed was the connection and the query.

If I remove the query the map shows without markers.

If I add the query the map disappears and tells me that initMap() is undefined. A var_dump shows that the query is working just fine.

What am I doing wrong?? this is really weird.

Thanks in advance for any help. I originally adapted the code from [here](http://tips4php.net/2010/10/use-php-mysql-and-google-map-api-v3-for-displaying-data-on-map/)

```
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
 new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: '<div style="color: #000">' + info + '</div>',
 maxWidth: 300,
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }

 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
 mapTypeControl: true,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
 }
 });
 <?php 
 $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM location");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $name=$row['name'];
 $addr1=$row['address'];
 $addr2=$row['address2'];
 $city=$row['city'];
 $state=$row['state'];
 $zip=$row['zip'];
 $country=$row['country'];
 $lat=$row['lat'];
 $lng=$row['lng'];

 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<p>". $name ."</p><br/>$addr2<br/>$city, $state $zip<br />$country');\n");
 }
 ?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
 }
 </script>

 </head>
 <body onLoad="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <div class="container">
<?php 
var_dump($lat, $lng, $addr2);
?>

<div class="content">   
<h1 class="marked" align="left">
  <div id="child" >The Big Map</div></h1><br />


  <br/>

<div id="map"></div><br/>
</div>     
<br/>
```

Comment: echo ("addMarker($lat, $lng,'<p>". $name ."</p><br/>$addr2<br/>$city, $state $zip<br />$country');\n"); baffles me. Why use string concatenation on one item ?

Comment: Two questions: why aren't you checking the return value from your query? I'd guess it's returning an error but you'd never know. Why are you selecting **everything** from the `location` table?

Comment: A third question: have you opened a database connection and initialised `$dbc`?

Comment: please check the console for further errors. We can't answer this without seeing the output of echo. Maybe the values stored in the DB contain some problematic characters(linebreaks or single-quote)

Comment: I'm very new to Google maps, so that's why the string concat. Do you have a better suggestion? I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: I was selecting everything because the variables are everything in the table. I checked the return and there is a syntax error on an item with a null lat/lng value.

Comment: W00t! Thanks for the help! I took away the NULL default in the table (to match the old db table) and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the new database had a NULL default in the lat/lng fields. I changed that to having no default (it is a float value btw). Thanks for the helpful comments.

Just so we all know, I'm self-taught and have huge gaps in my coding knowledge. If anyone wants to explain where and why my code could be better, the wisdom would be appreciated, Sensei.